# What should i use lme or glm? (Biostatistics, diversity)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, glmm, biostatistics

I am trying to work on the data of my master thesis. I have to create some model, but I am stuck due to my lack of knowledge in statistics (I am working on it). My data are 58 sample points each has two value: altitude and diversity index related to habitat heterogeneity. What I sample are different insects and I have two values: sp = number of species for each sample point and ab = abundance of insects for each sample point. What I wonder is if the number of species or the altitude is related to altitude or diversity index. My question is what should I use Linear mixed effect or generalized linear model?and in case which family? Poisson? but the most important question is how do I choose one or the other?

my data looks like this:

P.S: any literature is appreciated.

[image]